# RN 0.73.2 Xcode 15 Build target hermes-engine: Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-hermes

I am facing the following problem after running my project again, the pod installed successfully without any problem, but when running using yarn run ios command, the error as below occurs, has anyone encountered this? like me? please help me. Yesterday I ran React Native version 0.73.1 and it still worked fine. Today, when I upgraded to 0.73.2, the following problem occurred. I also downgraded back to 0.73.1 but still no luck.

[image]

Enviroments:

- Java 18
- React Native 0.73.2
- Xcode 15
- NodeJs 20